# Can I choose specific floor types?

Tags: tiny-tower

I am trying to get some dream jobs, e.g. plumber, I choose build specific floor, and go services, there is no plumber floor available!

Do I need a certain tower height? or a certain populace or something? or are the available floors I can build randomly assigned daily to my list?